# Attachment 0×0 size error

Tags: attachments, import, images

My theme uses 8 different thumbnail sizes. I imported my local installation to the final server using phpmyadmin to export the wordpress database.
Everything is smooth except for the attachments: many post thumbnails are broken. The file is there and displayed, but at the wrong size. When i open the file in the media library or in a post 's "Add image" interface, it displays that the image size is (0x0).

Only solution i find was to delete each post image and reupload it. Then it works, so it's the database import that's provoking the error.

I don't get how this error happens. Any idea? And how to fix it? The "Rebuild Thumbnails" plugin doesn't solve it unfortunately.

Comment: Are you doing anything with database other than straight 1:1 copying?

Comment: no, i'm not. just plain sql export > sql import.

Comment: But haven't you done a [serialized search/replace](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/) for the URLs? Don't you get any 404 (Chrome Inspector or Safari Activity Monitor) errors on media files? ::: Oh, just saw this is an old question... Found the cause?

Comment: Are you using Auto Post Thumbnail plugin? I wrote [a simple script](https://gist.github.com/3001048) to fix the missed attachments (it doesn't hurt your site), just try it.